# Получить id объекта из JSON

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Не могу получить ID объекта из JSON, знаю как получить количество объектов `${content.lenght}`, но не ID.

```js
async function getResponse() {
    const  response = await fetch('link')
    const content = await response.json()
    let items = document.querySelector('.items')
    console.log(content)
    let key

    for (key in content) {
      ${content.name}
    }
}
getResponse()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какое `id`? ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
${key}
```

отвечает за вывод того что мне было нужно

```js
async function getResponse() {
    const  response = await fetch('link')
    const content = await response.json()
    let items = document.querySelector('.items')
    console.log(content)
    let key

    for (key in content) {
      ${content.name}
      ${key}
    }
}
getResponse()
```

Answer (score 3):

По хорошему с бекенда вам должен прилетать `id` в каждом объекте, но я так понимаю у вас `id` не приходит, поэтому можно сделать так:

```js
(async () => {
    let response = await fetch(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
    )
    let users = await response.json()

    users.forEach((user, index) => {
      console.log(`name: ${user.name}, id: ${index}`)
    })
})()
```

В случае когда есть `id`:

```js
(async () => {
    let response = await fetch(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
    )
    let users = await response.json()

    users.forEach(user => {
      console.log(`name: ${user.name}, id: ${user.id}`)
    })
})()
```